# Android: Assign R.raw with variable

Tags: android, arrays, soundpool

I'm scanning my raw folder for files, and I want to assign these values to be scanned into the R.raw-path.

**Function for listing files in raw:**

```
public void listRaw(){
    Field[] fields=R.raw.class.getFields();
    for(int count=0; count < fields.length; count++){
        Log.i("R:", fields[count].getName()); 

    }
}
```

**Code for assigning the path for soundpool**

```
   sp = new SoundPool(99, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

    sound1 = sp.load(this, R.raw.kick, 1);
```

**I want something like:**

"sound1 = sp.load(this, R.raw.fields[count].getName(), 1);"

Answer (score 1):

Use `getIdentifier` method for accessing `id` of file using name:

```
int rawId = getResources().getIdentifier("raw/"+fields[count].getName(),
                                                   null, getPackageName());
sound1 = sp.load(this, rawId, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative can be:

```
   public void rawReflection()  {
        Field[] fields=R.raw.class.getFields();
        for(int count=0; count < fields.length; count++){
            Log.i("R:", fields[count].getName());

            try {

                //get the value(the ID) of the field
                int value= fields[count].getInt(R.raw.class);
                Log.i("value",value+"");
                sound1 = sp.load(this, value, 1);

            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```